# Group homology for a metacyclic group

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, finite-groups, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $M$ be a finitely generated $G$-module,
that is, a finitely generated abelian group on which $G$ acts.
We work with the first *homology* group
$$ H_1(G,M).$$

For any cyclic subgroup $C\subseteq G$, we consider the inclusion map
$i_C\colon C\hookrightarrow G$ and the induced homomorphism
$$ i_{C,*} \colon\, H_1(C,M)\to H_1(G,M).$$

Following Sansuc's paper of 1981, we say that $G$ is *metacyclic*
if all its Sylow subgroups are cyclic.
For example, the symmetric group $S_3$ is metacyclic.

> **Question.** Is it true that if $G$ is metacyclic in the sense of Sansuc, then the images
> $$ {\rm im}\big[i_{C,*}  \colon H_1(C,M)\to H_1(G,M)\big]$$
> for all cyclic subgroups $C$ of $G$ generate $H_1(G,M)$?

I expect the answer "Yes".
Note that when $G$ is *cyclic*, the answer is obviously "Yes".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name metacyclic is normally used for a group which is cyclic-by-cyclic (ie. a group $G$ with a cyclic normal subgroup $N$ such that $G/N$ is also cyclic). I will therefore refer to a finite group $G$ with cyclic Sylow subgroups as being *Sylow-cyclic*. One can show that such groups are in fact metacyclic in the above sense, but I wont use this.

The answer to the OP's question is yes: For $k\geq 1$, $H_k(G,M)$ is a finite abelian group so we can write it as a sum of it’s $p$-torsion parts $H_k(G,M) = \bigoplus_p H_k(G,M)_{(p)}$. If $S$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup the composite $H_k(G,M)\stackrel{\text{tr}}{\rightarrow} H_k(S,M)\stackrel{i_{S,*}}{\rightarrow} H_k(G,M)$ is multiplication by $[G:S]$. Looking at the $p$-torsion part the composite becomes an isomorphism, so $i_{S,*}\colon H_k(S,M) \rightarrow H_k(G,M)_{(p)}$ is surjective.

Thus $H_k(G,M)$ is always generated by the images  corresponding to the Sylow subgroups. If these are all cyclic then $H_k(G,M)$ is generated by images corresponding to cyclic subgroups.

Comment: The following seems to be a counter-example to your assertion. Let $G={\Bbb Z}/3{\Bbb Z}\times {\Bbb Z}/2{\Bbb Z}$, $M={\Bbb Z}$.
Then $$H_1(G,M)\cong G/[G,G]=G={\Bbb Z}/3{\Bbb Z}\times {\Bbb Z}/2{\Bbb Z},$$ whereas $$H_1(P,M)\cong{\Bbb Z}/3{\Bbb Z}/[{\Bbb Z}/3{\Bbb Z}, Z/3{\Bbb Z}]={\Bbb Z}/3{\Bbb Z}.$$

Comment: (cont.) Therefore, the natural homomorphism $H_1(P,M)\to H_1(G,M)$ cannot be surjective. What do you think about this?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi I replaced the original incorrect argument by a much simpler one.

Comment: Excellent! Many thanks! You write: $$H_k(G,M)\stackrel{\text{tr}}{\rightarrow} H_k(S,M)\stackrel{i_{S,*}}{\rightarrow} H_k(G,M)$$ is multiplication by $[G:S]$. What is $\rm tr$?  Is it the restriction map?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Yes $\text{tr}$ is short for transfer also known as restriction.

Answer (score 3):

Everything follows from the p-primary decomposition theorem, which is nicely explained in Ken Brown's group cohomology bible (Kasper's answer is the restriction-corestriction argument written circa Theorem III.10.3 for which you see that the p-primary component is the set of invariant-elements of the cohomology of a p-Sylow subgroup). As an aside / corollary, your group has periodic cohomology (Theorem VI.9.5), so you can learn a lot about your group / cohomology.

And Sansuc's definition of metacyclic is indeed unorthodox -- the usual definition is that it has an extension of a cyclic group by a cyclic group.* In particular, a group whose Sylow subgroups are cyclic is necessarily metacyclic, but the converse is not true: $\mathbb Z/3\times S_3$ has cyclic commutator subgroup (of order 3) whose quotient is cyclic (of order 6), but $\mathbb Z/3\times\mathbb Z/3$ is Sylow. What I think might be true of a metacyclic group is that its $p$-Sylow subgroups are cyclic for $p$ the smallest prime divisor of $|G|\ne p^n$.

*OK there is a 3rd notion of metacyclic, that its commutator subgroup and corresponding quotient are cyclic ($Q_8$ is not metacyclic in this sense but it is metacyclic in the cyclic-by-cyclic extension sense).

Comment: Unfortunately the last part isn’t true since $C_p\times C_p$ is metacyclic. Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: Ah! Perhaps $|G|\ne p^n$, but only inspired by https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272885/a-metacyclic-group-g-and-its-sylow-p-subgroup-where-p-is-the-smallest-pri which uses yet another distinct notion of metacyclic ($Q_8$ is metacyclic in my sense but not this reference sense).